# SQL query - unique values with multiple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query and I would need to modify that it counts the sums only for unique values in the Unit_Serial_No column (on the count I can easily do that with DISTINCT), I just don't know how to do with SUM. Thanks in advance!

```
 SELECT COUNT(Test_Result) as 'Total' 
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Test_Result='Pass' THEN 1 END) AS 'Passed'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Test_Result='Fail' THEN 1 END) AS 'Failed'
 FROM [Optima_Test_Results].[dbo].[Optima PreChamber Test]
 WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Created_Date)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Solution, with little adjustments, credit to Madhivanan:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Unit_Serial_No) as 'Total' 
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Test_Result='Pass' THEN Unit_Serial_No END) AS 'Passed'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Test_Result='Fail' THEN Unit_Serial_No  END) AS 'Failed'
 FROM [Optima_Test_Results].[dbo].[Optima PreChamber Test]
 WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Created_Date)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: You want the `Sum` of `Unit_Serial_No` or the `Count`? It sounds that this column is for serial-numbers which you normally don't sum.

Comment: Count all the unique serial numbers for today and return 2 numbers, one sum of the passes one sum of the fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Test_Result) as 'Total' 
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Test_Result='Pass' THEN serial_no  END) AS 'Passed'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Test_Result='Fail' THEN serial_no  END) AS 'Failed'
 FROM [Optima_Test_Results].[dbo].[Optima PreChamber Test]
 WHERE 
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Created_Date)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks! With a little mod, it is exactly I looked for :) I posted the correct query in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This query can help if you don't have different results for same tests. Otherwise they will be counted twice: once for 'Passed' and once for 'Failed':

```
;WITH uniquevalues AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Unit_Serial_No, Test_Result
    FROM [Optima_Test_Results].[dbo].[Optima PreChamber Test]
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Created_Date)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
)
SELECT COUNT(Test_Result) as 'Total' 
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Test_Result='Pass' THEN 1 END) AS 'Passed'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Test_Result='Fail' THEN 1 END) AS 'Failed'
 FROM uniquevalues
```